# Failed audit because OP deleted their own question

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, reopen-closed

Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/23805040) really deserve being closed? It seems clear to me, and the OP has also showed their effort.

I assume reopening it is considered incorrect by the system, because that question has been deleted by the OP.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a reasonable audit, in my mind.

The question here illustrates what happens when someone "checks a box" by just adding some code. It's enough code to fool most people, but the real heart of the matter is never the code.

It's what the issue the OP ran into *with* the code.

Here, the OP has the problem of not really knowing what to do.  That's probably okay; they wouldn't be asking us questions if they *knew* what to do.  But we're not asking them if they know what they're doing; we're asking them if they've actually done something to get close to the level they want.

At this point it's incredibly unclear what they experienced or encountered.  The edit was intended to make it *better*, but it really didn't since it lacked the critical detail of **what issue they encountered with their code**, so there's not much we can do with a question like this.

Always be sure to look beneath the covers.  Someone posting a smattering of code is not the same as them showing *effort*.